# Имитация F11 на javascript

Tags: javascript

Подкиньте js скрипт, который, скажем, по window.onload или onclick будет отображать окно браузера как fullscreen без нажатия на F11. Реализацию на Jquery или работу через window.open просьба не предлагать.

Comment: оу, реклама выходит на новый уровень:) теперь будет во весь экран.

Comment: нет, админка выходит на новый уровень)

Comment: Мое мнение - не нужно разворачивать пользователю браузер во весь экран. Нужно - нажмет.

Comment: Пользователь это всего видеть не будет! админка делается под закрытый круг людей.

Comment: Если я верно помню, то можно открыть новое окно в фуллскрин

Comment: дело в том что текущее окно должно при загрузке сразу становится в fullscreen. решение ищу.

Comment: Как вариант есть есть prism  у firefox <a href="http://prism.mozillalabs.com/">Prizm</a>, подобное также есть у chrome и что-то очень страшное есть у IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var el = document.documentElement
    , rfs = // for newer Webkit and Firefox
           el.requestFullScreen
        || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
        || el.mozRequestFullScreen
;
if(typeof rfs!="undefined" && rfs){
  rfs.call(el);
} else if(typeof window.ActiveXObject!="undefined"){
  // for Internet Explorer
  var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  if (wscript!=null) {
     wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
  }
}
```

Comment: ни в одном браузере не работает! :(